# Are tobacco packaging warning messages improving health of society?

Tags: smoking, labeling, side-effects, tobacco, public-awareness

Are there any countries with law not requiring such warnings? If yes, were there conducted any smokers-related studies?

Answer (score 6):

There are some studied done about it. Here is the list of them

1. [Effectiveness of cigarette warning labels](http://tobaccocontrol.bmj.com/content/15/suppl_3/iii19.full.html)
2. [Perceived Believability of Warning Label Information](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00913367.1988.10673110)
3. [Do Cigarette Warning Labels Reduce Smoking?](http://archpedi.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=518297)

[Another study](http://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/abs/10.2105/AJPH.94.8.1442) came up with

> Approximately one fifth of participants [by the way there are 616 adult smokers] reported smoking less as a result of the labels; only 1% reported smoking more. Although participants reported negative emotional responses to the warnings including fear (44%) and disgust (58%), smokers who reported greater negative emotion were more likely to have quit, attempted to quit, or reduced their smoking 3 months later. Participants who attempted to avoid the warnings (30%) were no less likely to think about the warnings or engage in cessation behavior at follow-up.